# Make event onclick after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

So, I have a little problem with finding selectors.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
    alert("hello!");
});
```

So, that code works fine if I need to find all checkboxes on the page. BUT!
I need to find checkboxes, that are inside

```
<ul id="sortable-menu">
  <li>
     <input type="checkbox" id=${category['id']} />//so, id is dynamic
  </li>
</ul>
```

Please, help to solve my little issue. Thanks!

Comment: Change your selector to `#sortable-menu input[type=checkbox]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use closest static parent for delegated event

```
$('#sortable-menu').on('click', ':checkbox', function () {
    alert("hello!");
});
```

If `sortable-menu` is also dynamically generated

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortable-menu :checkbox', function () {
    alert("hello!");
});
```

In place of `document` always use closest static container for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

What are you passing to jQuery is a CSS selector, so you could just describe the structure you are looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortable-menu li input[type=checkbox]', function () {
    alert("hello!");
});
```